# How to get list of files for every commit with octokit and c#

Tags: c#, .net, github-api, octokit.net

I have one class GitHub with one method which should return list of all commits for specific username and repo on GitHub:

```
using System;
using Octokit;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ReadRepo
{
    public class GitHub
    {
        public GitHub()
        {
        }

        public async Task<List<GitHubCommit>> getAllCommits()
        {            
            string username = "lukalopusina";
            string repo = "flask-microservices-main";

            var github = new GitHubClient(new ProductHeaderValue("MyAmazingApp"));
            var repository = await github.Repository.Get(username, repo);
            var commits = await github.Repository.Commit.GetAll(repository.Id);

            List<GitHubCommit> commitList = new List<GitHubCommit>();

            foreach(GitHubCommit commit in commits) {
                commitList.Add(commit);
            }

            return commitList;
        }

    }
}
```

And I have main function which call getAllCommits method:

```
using System;
using Octokit;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ReadRepo
{
    class MainClass
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {            

            GitHub github = new GitHub();

            Task<List<GitHubCommit>> commits = github.getAllCommits();
            commits.Wait(10000);

            foreach(GitHubCommit commit in commits.Result) {                
                foreach (GitHubCommitFile file in commit.Files)
                    Console.WriteLine(file.Filename);    
            }

        }
    }
}
```

When I run this i get following error:

[image]

**Problem is because this variable commit.Files is Null probably because of async call but I am not sure how to solve it. Please some help?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is if you need to get a list of files for all the commits you will need to get each commit separately by using

```
foreach(GitHubCommit commit in commits) 
{
    var commitDetails = github.Repository.Commit.Get(commit.Sha);
    var files = commitDetails.Files;
}
```

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/issues/1293). There's also decribed another approach to reach your goal - at first get the list of all files in a repository and then get the list of commits for each file.

Comment: You are right in order to get Files I need for every commit to perform one more query and also you are right that it is better strategy to get list of files and then for every file to git all versions. Thanks.

Comment: I also edited your code example with working example I tested.